# Properties set in init are nil right after in viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm running into an issue where a derived class sets a property defined in the super class in its initWithNibName call and by the time viewDidLoad is called, the property is magically undefined again. It goes something like:

```
@interface BaseClassController : UIViewController
{
}

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *myString; // synthesized in the .m
```

in another file

```
@interface DerivedClassController : BaseClassController
{
}
```

and in its implementation:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"Setting MyString stuff");
        self.myString = @"Hi Mom";
        NSLog(@"Done setting myString");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"MyString is %@", self.myString); // output as (null)!!!
    [...]
}
```

According to the output of NSLog the order is correct, I know for a fact that viewDidLoad isn't being called first: first the initWithNibName method, then viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad reports self.myString as (null) every single time. However if I move the initialization of myString down to viewDidLoad, everything works fine. Why? I must be missing something really obvious here..

**Edit:**

Not sure if this makes a difference, but the DerivedClassController is the root view controller of a navigation controller that's being presented modally (for all sorts of legacy reasons).

**Edit 2:**

The code works as expected in a stand-alone xcode project, it fails when imported into the project where I'll ultimately need to use it.

Comment: Believe it or not, exactly the same just happened to me as well.  A property set in ``init`` is nil in ``viewDidLoad``. I tried not using the synthesized accessors by setting ``_myString`` directly, to no avail.  That was really, really hard to debug, because it's not a programming error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you're logging from the same controller both times? Like, perhaps you're calling `initWithNibName:bundle:` on one controller, but then `viewDidLoad` is actually called on another controller?

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason why you have it set to copy?

Try setting the property to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;
```

Comment: The copy is a standard practice in iOS, here's the clarification from the guys at Big Nerd Ranch: "In general, when you have a property that points to an instance of a class that has a mutable subclass (like NSString or NSArray), it is safer to make
a copy of the object to point to rather than pointing to an existing object that could have other owners."

I still tried changing to strong, didn't make a difference based on what I saw.

(Btw, I'm not the one down-voting)